# Big part of partition not accessible

Tags: partitioning, gparted

A big part of my file system partition either seems to be corrupted or is not accessible. GParted shows me these confusing numbers for used/unused space that do not match the total size.

[image: Gparted Screenshot]

Comment: What is the SMART status in Disks?

Comment: Since NTFS, have you run chkdsk from Windows? Do not edit NTFS partitions with gparted especially if showing errors like it is. Use Windows tools for Windows.

Comment: Think I saw another question like this a couple weeks ago.  Think it because it was an logical partition with a part unallocated.  I could be remembering wrong.  The picture looked almost the same, part of partition had used and unused space and the rest was grey out.

Comment: Thank you for all your replies. I will try chkdsk

Comment: Chkdsk reported no errors, unfortunately. Now I don't know how to fix the partition.

Comment: What OS are you using? Please [edit] your answer and add the output of `uname -a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partition-size and filesystem-size are different things. In your case, the file-system is just much smaller than the partition. What you need to do, is to resize your filesystem.

In Ubuntu, you can do that with the `ntfsresize`-command:

- First unmount the partition with `sudo umount /dev/sda1`.
- Second run `sudo ntfsresize --check /dev/sda1` to make sure the filesystem is ready to resize.
- Third run `sudo ntfsresize /dev/sda1` to enlarge the filesystem and fit the partition-size. This will trigger `chkdsk` to be run the next time you start Windows.
- Last boot into Windows to run the filsystem-check.

Please take a look into `man ntfsresize` before doing all this.

Comment: That's it, thank you! For documentation purposes, in my case I did it like that:

`sudo ntfsresize --size 853402451968 /dev/sda1 `

Because `sudo ntfsresize -n --size 8G /dev/sda1` returned this:


`Current volume size: 146800636416 bytes (146801 MB)


Current device size: 853402451968 bytes (853403 MB)


New volume size    : 853402448384 bytes (853403 MB) `

Unfortuantely my files did not grow back but that is another chapter.